# Is there a limit on how many divs a vue component has to have so it can be displayed as a microfrontend?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, webpack, micro-frontend

I made this webpack module federation microfrontend project that consists a vue project that contains a vue component that should be displayed in another vue project.

So I have a vue component like this and it doesn't get displayed:

```
<template>
   <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="block">
          <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
          <div class="column has-text-grey">by x</div>
          <div class="column has-text-grey">12/12/32 12:34</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
          voluptatem harum praesentium quas voluptatibus nostrum debitis totam
          tempore, et dolor unde incidunt hic recusandae ipsa facilis quaerat
          quod sequi nulla?
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <div class="tags">
            <span class="tag">tag </span>
            <span class="tag">tag </span>
            <span class="tag">tag </span>
            <span class="tag">tag </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have noticed that if I remove some divs it does eventually get displayed, like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="block">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
          voluptatem harum praesentium quas voluptatibus nostrum debitis totam
          tempore, et dolor unde incidunt hic recusandae ipsa facilis quaerat
          quod sequi nulla?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there a limit?, how can I change it?

this are the webpack configs:
for the project that provides data:

```
const path = require("path");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
module.exports = (env = {}) => ({
  mode: "development",
  cache: false,
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  target: "web",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.js"),
  // output: {
  //   path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  //   publicPath: '/dist/'
  // },
  output: {
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".vue", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: {
      // this isn't technically needed, since the default `vue` entry for bundlers
      // is a simple `export * from '@vue/runtime-dom`. However having this
      // extra re-export somehow causes webpack to always invalidate the module
      // on the first HMR update and causes the page to reload.
      vue: "@vue/runtime-dom",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: { limit: 8192 },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {},
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "home",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        home: "home@http://localhost:8002/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      exposes: {
        "./Content": "./src/components/Content",
        "./Button": "./src/components/Button",
        "./Post": "./src/components/Post",
        "./Test": "./src/components/Test"
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html"),
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8002,
    hot: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
});
```

For the project that reads data:

```
const path = require("path");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
module.exports = (env = {}) => ({
  mode: "development",
  cache: false,
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  target: "web",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.js"),
  output: {
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".vue", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: {
      // this isn't technically needed, since the default `vue` entry for bundlers
      // is a simple `export * from '@vue/runtime-dom`. However having this
      // extra re-export somehow causes webpack to always invalidate the module
      // on the first HMR update and causes the page to reload.
      vue: "@vue/runtime-dom",
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: { limit: 8192 },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {},
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "layout",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        home: "home@http://localhost:8002/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      exposes: {},
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html"),
      chunks: ["main"],
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8001,
    hot: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: When you say 'doesn't get displayed' what do you mean? Does the page not contain the HTML? Or is it rendered in an unexpected way? Your first and 2nd example have different CSS classes on different elements (e.g. `columns`) which might be a factor here.

Comment: @match, thanks for the reply, I coppied the element wrong in the post and edited it, both are the same. In the browser inspect it appears like this `<div class="columns" data-v-64778763=""></div>`  an empty div tag.

Comment: there is no limit, your problem must be somewhere else (have you tried adding one div at a time until it stops working for example?), are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors, yeah i did remove divs one by one until it worked

Comment: i do have this warning `[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: Symbol(Static) (symbol) 
  at <Post> 
  at <AsyncComponentWrapper> 
  at <Layout>`